# Issue with Leaflet Pop-up Box - Small tag on corner of box. Is this a glitch of some kind?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, maps

I set up a leaflet map recently with tool tips that pop up on click. I thought everything was working perfectly until someone pointed out that each pop up box has this weird tag in the bottom right hand corner (see image below).

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Here's the code for the popup:

```
function popUp (feature, layer) {
   layer.bindPopup("<h1 class='city_infoheader'>" + feature.properties.city + " </h1><p>PM2.5 Attributable COPD Deaths: "+Math.round(feature.properties.copd) + "</p>");
   layer.setIcon(circle);
};

function PoppopUp (feature, layer) {
   layer.bindPopup("<h1 class='infoheader'>"+feature.properties.admin+" </h1><p>Country Population: "+feature.properties.pop_est+"</p>");
}; 

var pmDeaths = new L.geoJson(pmDeaths,{
    onEachFeature: popUp,
}).addTo(mymap);

var countryPop = new L.geoJson(countryPop,{
    style:countryColor,
    onEachFeature: PoppopUp,
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Please include your code with your attempt so far.

Comment: @kboul added. see above.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the problem. Maybe `layer.setIcon(circle);` causes a distortion in the popup (what about the icon code?) but I can't say for sure if I don't see a working example. The code you provided looks ok with a quick look. Should be a css issue I guess.

Comment: you can see the whole map at http://graphics.haqastindicators.org/htmlblank.html

Comment: Just a quick notice. Your page takes 16s to load which is a huge response time and causes a bad user experience due to `countryPop.js` file

Comment: There is sth wrong with the `.leaflet-popup-tip-container`. It is the arrow below the popup that indicates the marker once you clicked it. It has been distorted for some reason. Best quick solution would be to set the css class selector to `.leaflet-popup-tip-container { display: none; }`

Comment: Thanks @kboul, I am aware that the site is quite slow right now. I may remove the country pop layer or research other ways to increase speed. I'm still new to leaflet so I haven't gotten that far in the learning process. I was able to change the display setting on the container and it seems to have resolved the issue for now. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer since it helped you if I write it on the answer block?

Comment: @kboul yes, I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sth wrong with the `.leaflet-popup-tip-container`. 
It is the arrow below the popup that indicates the marker once you clicked it. 
It has been distorted for some reason. Best quick solution would be to set the css class selector to:

```
.leaflet-popup-tip-container { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  If you are including leaflet.css in addition to a library that already contains leaflet (e.g., mapbox), then there may be duplication/conflict of style definitions that will cause this problem with the popup tips.  The solution is to remove leaflet.css from your build.